# stringr::str_extract_all - how to increase speed/alternatives?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have several hundred documents of multiple pages with text which I extract from the web. I am trying to extract all country names which appear in the text plus e.g. 10 words before and after each match/country name.

So far i made use of the `countrycode` package which contains a dataframe `codelist` which contains names of basically all countries (as well as `reprex` versions of these names).

I pulled these names into one long vector, collapsed it with the OR sign "|" as a separator and use the resulting string as regex in stringr's `str_extract_all`. The approach by and large works, however, it is quite slow for my liking.

Checking only the first 1500 characters of one single document takes 40 seconds on my (average) laptop (16 gig, i5-8625U). Running the script on all my documents will probably take more than a day.

Hence, my question - how can I increase the speed of extracting country names and their neighboring words? Since this is a task I am regularly requiring I am happy also to take up other tools (Julia? Python?).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(countrycode)
library(rvest)
library(tictoc)

df_main <-c("http://docstore.ohchr.org/SelfServices/FilesHandler.ashx?enc=6QkG1d%2fPPRiCAqhKb7yhssh2tXWBbyLwahMw00Sn91Vx2CtIqUsxb8GHTWZijKzuMBGT4crbn9EZ8sIYVnIZ4cuyvgS8esYaZB%2bpIm6AjmiXFUTphoU1fK%2blmqzGzjoi8BFXLvYtOrKwuZsRFFTmN0umUat3QkQ%2bVArWqePYKE8%3d") %>%  
  enframe(name=NULL,
          value="doc_link")



fn_get_doc_text <- function(doc_link) {
  xml2::read_html(doc_link) %>% 
    rvest::html_text()
}

df_main <- df_main %>% 
  mutate(doc_text=map_chr(doc_link, possibly(fn_get_doc_text, otherwise="missing"))) %>% 
  mutate(doc_intro=str_sub(doc_text, end=1500) %>% str_squish())

df_country_patterns <- countrycode::codelist %>% 
  select(country.name.en) %>% 
  mutate(country_pattern=paste0("(\\S+\\s+){0,10}", country.name.en, "(\\s+\\S+){0,10}"))

vec_country_patterns <- df_country_patterns %>% 
  pull(country_pattern) %>% 
  paste(., collapse="|")

# stringr -----------------------------------------------------------------


tic()
df_main <- df_main %>% 
  mutate(countries_detected=str_extract_all(doc_intro, regex(vec_country_patterns, 
                                                            ignore_case = F,
                                                            dotall = T)))
toc()  
#> 41.34 sec elapsed
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I would definitely give a try to Python's `re.findall` although you may need to loop over your dictionary of possible matches: https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html#7

Comment: Also, can you try simplifying the regexp forgetting initially about the 10 words before and after? Just to check if that makes a difference. In case it did, you could always do a first search without including that words, and a second search of the matches to add them afterwards.

Comment: You can also do some profiling by printing out the times taken by different parts of your code, trying to identify where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Finally, make sure you're not executing many times a task that should only be executed once. E.g. creating the dictionary of possible country names every time you want to search for a match.

Comment: Try the package [re2r](https://github.com/qinwf/re2r).  It gave me a big speed-up.

Comment: Is there any reason you tagged this `Julia`? Perhaps if you want to ask about strategies in Julia for such job asking a separate question would be a good idea.

Comment: Adding to Michaels suggestion of using re2r, there's some benchmarks between `stringi` and `re2r` (by different use-cases & contexts) that might help you to optimize your regex search: https://qinwenfeng.com/re2r_doc/benchmark.html